# How to create c++ windows desktop application in visual studio 2017?

Tags: visual-c++

I am using visual studio 2017 and windows 10 operating system. I am trying to create windows desktop application but I have no idea how to create

I followed this page of Microsoft  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/walkthrough-creating-windows-desktop-applications-cpp?view=vs-2019

I don't get three check box in step three

if I tick on empty project, precompiled header check automatically remove or if I tick on precompiled header, empty project automatically remove

I don't understand what's wrong happen

I found the another link https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a9529502-6304-4aa6-90ee-0757ab258d87/create-c-windows-forms-application-in-visual-studio-2017?forum=winforms

But I don't know is it way to create  desktop application in c++

I hope someone help me in right direction

Answer (score 2):

You have to **Modify** Visual Studio Installer 2017 and click **Desktop application with C++** 
Compare your Installation details with this pic [image]

Comment: thanks akash How do you create a desktop application in c++

Comment: I usually use MFC

Comment: I am beginner  Why do you use MFC why not other ?

Comment: I worked in CAD Software. Most of the Application already developed in MFC and it will be very expencive if they convert into new technology. For add on we have to use MFC only